# Conditional statements using Chosen pluggin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I created a couple inputs and drop downs that feed into a JavaScript command to create custom sentences. Whatever the user inputs or selects is added to a sentence framework. When the user selects submit, the sentence is created. It is quite simple. I am running into trouble trying to create a conditional statement for one of the inputs.

If the user selects "No" within the "Curb Rash?" drop down, the text from "input5" and "input6" still appears. This text reads "It has minor curb rash on the " and "It has major curb rash on the ". How can I change the code so that if "No" is selected these inputs do not appear within the sentence?

Currently if "no" is selected it reads (**note the first input I added was "2012 VW GTI" and the last was "red"):

"This is my 2012 VW GTI. It is in good condition. The vehicle's rims have no curb rash. It has minor curb rash on the . It has major curb rash on the . The 2012 VW GTI's color is red."

How I want it to read if "no" is selected:

"This is my 2012 VW GTI. It is in good condition. The vehicle's rims have no curb rash. The 2012 VW GTI's color is red."

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <title>Hi</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

 <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
  .chosen-select {width:200px}
 </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";

    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();
    }

    else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;

      var input2;
      if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "none") {
        input2 = "The vehicle's rims have no curb rash"
        }
      else if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "yes"){
        input2 = "The vehicle's rims have curb rash"
      }


            var input3 = $('#z3').val();
            console.log(input3);

            var input3Formatted = "";
            if(input3.length==1){
              // Only one value...
              input3Formatted = input3[0];
            }
            if(input3.length==2){
              // Two values... Just add and "and"
              input3Formatted = input3[0]+" and "+input3[1];
            }
            if(input3.length>2){
              // more than 2 values...
              for(i=0;i<input3.length-1;i++){
                input3Formatted += input3[i]+", ";
              }
              input3Formatted += "and "+input3[input3.length-1];
            }


            var input4 = $('#z4').val();
            console.log(input4);

            var input4Formatted = "";
            if(input4.length==1){
              // Only one value...
              input4Formatted = input4[0];
            }
            if(input4.length==2){
              // Two values... Just add and "and"
              input4Formatted = input4[0]+" and "+input4[1];
            }
            if(input4.length>2){
              // more than 2 values...
              for(i=0;i<input4.length-1;i++){
                input4Formatted += input4[i]+", ";
              }
              input4Formatted += "and "+input4[input4.length-1];
            }

            const input5 = "It has minor curb rash on the "+input3Formatted+"."
            const input6 = "It has major curb rash on the "+input4Formatted+"."
            const input7 = document.getElementById("z5").value;




      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "This is my " +input1+ ". It is in good condition. " +input2+". "+input5+" "+input6+" The "+input1+"'s color is "+input7+"."

    }
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 4
    });

     $("#z2").chosen().change(function(){
      if ($(this).val() === 'none'){
        $("#z3").parent().hide();
        $("#z4").parent().hide();
      }
      else if ($(this).val() === 'yes'){
        $("#z3").parent().show();
        $("#z4").parent().show();
      }
  });


    function hide() {
      $("#z3").parent().hide();
      $("#z4").parent().hide();
    }
    // call hide AFTER .chosen() has been invoked on the visible elements
    hide();

  });
</script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
          <td>
            <select data-placeholder="Curb Rash?" name="curbrash" class="chosen-select" id="z2">
              <option value="" disabled selected></option>
              <option value="yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="none">No</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select data-placeholder="Minor Curb Rash" name="minorrash" multiple class="chosen-select" id="z3">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="front left rim">Front Left Rim</option>
              <option value="back left rim">Back Left Rim</option>
              <option value="front right rim">Front Right Rim</option>
              <option value="back right rim">Back Right Rim</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select data-placeholder="Major Curb Rash" name="majorrash" multiple class="chosen-select" id="z4">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="front left rim">Front Left Rim</option>
              <option value="back left rim">Back Left Rim</option>
              <option value="front right rim">Front Right Rim</option>
              <option value="back right rim">Back Right Rim</option>
            </selct>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="z5" placeholder="Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
    <br>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just save the sentence in a variable, so this line:

```html
      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "This is my " +input1+ ". It is in good condition. " +input2+". "+input5+" "+input6+" The "+input1+"'s color is "+input7+"."
```

would instead just be:

```html
      document.getElementById("s1").value = WhateverVariable
```

You can then set WhateverVariable inside conditionals (adding the input4/input5 if needed), growing the string as you continue on with the inputs.